# IOS parent ViewController original coordinate missed after getting child ViewCOntroller Data

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-maps-markers, protocols

I have implemented the module to pass the values from child viewController (SliderViewController ) to master viewController (MapViewController) but when it comes to the implementation, the position just added is lost and hence the array of coordinates cannot be added and hence presented? Besides saving the coordinates into the text file and reload, are there any other alternatives to save the array of coordinates ?

The below is my working:

**ChildViewCOntroller**

SliderViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "EFCircularSlider.h"



@protocol SliderViewControllerDelegate <NSObject>
- (void)passData:(float )itemVertical : (float )itemCircular  ;
@end


@interface SliderViewController : UIViewController

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *uiValue;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UISlider *uiSlider;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *btnReset;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *uiValue2;
@property (strong, nonatomic)  EFCircularSlider* circularSlider;
@property (nonatomic) float verticalSliderValue;
@property (nonatomic) float circleSliderValue;
@property (nonatomic) id <SliderViewControllerDelegate> delegate;


- (IBAction)reset:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)sliderChange:(id)sender;
- (void)buttonClicked: (id)sender;


@end
```

SliderViewController.m

```
#import "SliderViewController.h"
#import <AudioToolbox/AudioServices.h>
#import "MapViewController.h"

@interface SliderViewController (){
    NSString *valueV;
    NSString *valueC;
}

@end

@implementation SliderViewController



- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    _uiSlider.minimumValue = 0.0;
    _uiSlider.maximumValue = 100.0;
    [_uiSlider removeConstraints:_uiSlider.constraints];
    [_uiSlider setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:YES];

    float value  = M_PI * -0.5 ;
   _uiSlider.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(value);

    CGRect sliderFrame = CGRectMake(60, 300, 100, 100);
   _circularSlider = [[EFCircularSlider alloc] initWithFrame:sliderFrame];
    [_circularSlider addTarget:self action:@selector(valueChanged:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
    [self.view addSubview:_circularSlider];
    [_circularSlider setCurrentValue:10.0f];
    [_uiSlider setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithWhite:0.0 alpha:0.5]];

    CGRect screen = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
    CGFloat width = CGRectGetWidth(screen);
    CGFloat height = CGRectGetHeight(screen);
    float scale = [[UIScreen mainScreen] scale];

    UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    button.frame = CGRectMake( 0, 450 ,width/2, 20);
    [button setTitle:@"OK" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    button.titleLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:16.0];
    button.titleLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = TRUE;
    [button setBackgroundColor:[UIColor orangeColor]];

    [button addTarget: self
               action: @selector(buttonClicked:)
     forControlEvents: UIControlEventTouchDown];


    [self.view addSubview:button];
}


- (void) buttonClicked: (id)sender
{
    NSLog( @"Button clicked." );
}



- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
}

-(void)valueChanged:(EFCircularSlider*)slider {
    self.uiValue2.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.02f", slider.currentValue ];
    _circleSliderValue = slider.currentValue;
    valueC =  self.uiValue2.text;
    if(slider.currentValue  > 20.0 && slider.currentValue  < 30.0  ){
        AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(1003);
        AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(kSystemSoundID_Vibrate);
    }
}

- (IBAction)reset:(id)sender {
    [self writeToTextFile:valueV :valueC];
    MapViewController * sliderVC = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"MapViewController"];
    sliderVC.verticalSliderValue = _uiSlider.value;
    sliderVC.circleSliderValue =_circularSlider.currentValue;
    [sliderVC passData:_uiSlider.value :_circularSlider.currentValue  ];
    sliderVC.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationCurrentContext;
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
  }

-(void) writeToTextFile:(NSString*) values : (NSString*) values2 {
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains
    (NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *fileName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/slider.txt",documentsDirectory];
    NSString *content = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@%@%@", values , @"\n" , values2 , @"\n" ];
    [content writeToFile:fileName
              atomically:YES
                encoding:NSStringEncodingConversionAllowLossy
                   error:nil];
      NSLog(@"%@",documentsDirectory);
    [self displayContent];
}

-(void) displayContent{
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains
    (NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *fileName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/slider.txt",
                          documentsDirectory];
    NSString *content = [[NSString alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:fileName
                                                    usedEncoding:nil
                                                           error:nil];
    NSLog(@"%@",content);
}


- (IBAction)sliderChange:(id)sender {
    UISlider *slider = (UISlider *)sender;
    NSString *newValue = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2f" , slider.value];
    _verticalSliderValue = slider.value;
    self.uiValue.text = newValue;
    valueV  = self.uiValue.text;
    if(slider.value > 30 && slider.value < 50){
        AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(1003);
        AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(kSystemSoundID_Vibrate);
    }
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return (interfaceOrientation != UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown);
}

@end
```

***MasterViewController***

MapViewController.h

```
    #import <MessageUI/MessageUI.h>
    #import <GoogleMaps/GoogleMaps.h>
    #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
    #import "SliderViewController.h"


    @interface MapViewController : UIViewController<GMSMapViewDelegate , SliderViewControllerDelegate>{


    }

    @property (nonatomic) float verticalSliderValue;
    @property (nonatomic) float circleSliderValue;


    @end

MapViewCntroller.m



#import "MapViewController.h"
#import "CheckPoints.h"
#import "NSURLRequestSSL.h"
#import "ToastView.h"


@interface MapViewController () {
    GMSMapView *mapView_;
    NSMutableArray *array;
    GMSCameraPosition *camera;
    NSArray *_styles;
    NSArray *_lengths;
    NSArray *_polys;
    double _pos, _step;
    CLLocationCoordinate2D p;
}


@end

@implementation MapViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    [self getTime];
    array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    // Create a GMSCameraPosition that tells the map to display the
    // coordinate -33.86,151.20 at zoom level 6.uisplatch

    camera = [GMSCameraPosition cameraWithLatitude:22.2855200
                                                            longitude:114.1576900
                                                                 zoom:12];
    mapView_ = [GMSMapView mapWithFrame:CGRectZero camera:camera];
    mapView_.delegate = self;

    mapView_.myLocationEnabled = YES;
    mapView_.settings.compassButton = YES;
    mapView_.settings.myLocationButton = YES;
    // mapView_.delegate = self;
    self.view = mapView_;

    // Creates a marker in the center of the map.
    GMSMarker *marker = [[GMSMarker alloc] init];
    marker.position = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(22.2855200, 114.1576900);
    marker.title = @"My place";


    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    // defaults
    float latitide = [defaults floatForKey:@"lati"];
    float longitude = [defaults floatForKey:@"longi"];
    NSString *desp = [defaults objectForKey:@"desp"];

    if(latitide!=0.00&&longitude!=0.00) {
        CLLocationCoordinate2D position = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(latitide, longitude);
        marker.position = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(position.latitude, position.longitude);
    }
    if(desp.length > 0 ){
        marker.title = desp;
    }

    marker.snippet = @"HK";
    marker.map = mapView_;

}


...


    - (void)passData:(float )value1 : (float )valueCiruclar
{
 NSLog(@"This was returned from ViewControllerB %ff",value1);
    NSLog(@"This was returned from ViewControllerSlider %ff",valueCiruclar);


    [mapView_ clear];

    NSLog(@"This was map received");

    CheckPoints *myCar=[[CheckPoints alloc] init];

    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

    float latitide = [defaults floatForKey:@"lati"];
    float longitude = [defaults floatForKey:@"longi"];
    NSString *desp = [defaults objectForKey:@"desp"];



    [myCar setLatitude:latitide];
    [myCar setLongitude:longitude];
    [myCar setDesp:desp];
    [myCar setState:[desp length] > 0 ? 0 : 1];



    [CarArray addObject:myCar];


    NSLog(@"This was returned lat from ViewControllerB %ff",[myCar getLatitude]);
    NSLog(@"This was returned longi from ViewControllerSlider %ff",[myCar getLongitude]);
    NSLog(@"This was returned desp from ViewControllerB %@",[myCar getDesp]);
    NSLog(@"This was returned state from ViewControllerSlider %i",[myCar getState]);

    lastChk = CarArray.lastObject;
    [self writeToTextFile:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@%@%@%@%@", lastChk.getDesp , @"\n",[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", lastChk.getLatitude],
                           @"\n", [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", lastChk.getLongitude], @"\n" ]];

    NSLog(@"This was map arraoy count @%i" , [CarArray count]);

    for (int i = 0; i < [CarArray count]; i++) {
        CheckPoints *current =  [CarArray objectAtIndex:i];
        if(current.getLatitude != lastChk.getLatitude && current.getLongitude != lastChk.getLongitude){
            [current setState:1];
            NSString* previousTitle = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", @"Checkpoint" ,[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", i+1]];
            [current setDesp:previousTitle];
        }
    }
    [self addMarkers];








    -(void) mapView:(GMSMapView *)mapView didLongPressAtCoordinate:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)coordinate{

        p = coordinate;
        SliderViewController * sliderVC = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"SliderViewController"];
        sliderVC.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:1.0 alpha:1.0];
        sliderVC.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationCurrentContext;
        [self presentViewController:sliderVC animated:YES completion:NULL];

    }
```

Comment: Did you check the passData: is invoked?

Comment: Do you mean that parameters of passData: is nil?

Comment: @trick14 it is the original data of the variables being set in the parent viewcontroller is wiped away

Comment: Let me clear the problem. I'm not sure it is what you want. You have a parent view controller(MapViewController) and presented a child view controller(SliderViewController). You want send some data to parent view controller with the reset: and delegate. In the reset method, you instantiate master View Controller again. It's not the same instance of parent view controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
-(void) mapView:(GMSMapView *)mapView didLongPressAtCoordinate:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)coordinate
{
    p = coordinate;
    SliderViewController * sliderVC = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"SliderViewController"];
    sliderVC.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:1.0 alpha:1.0];
    sliderVC.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationCurrentContext;
    **[sliderVC setDelegate:self]**
    [self presentViewController:sliderVC animated:YES completion:NULL];
}
```

and

```
- (IBAction)reset:(id)sender 
{
    [self writeToTextFile:valueV :valueC];
    [self.delegate passData:_uiSlider.value :_circularSlider.currentValue  ];
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Don't create a new instance. What you need is just use delegate.